# Sharing Memory on uwsgi python application

Tags: python, uwsgi, python-multiprocessing

I have a python flask web api application, hosted the behind the uwsgi with processes=4.

When I create a dictionary with Multiprocessing.Manager.dict(), the dictonary is not shared across the processes. Each process has its own dict object.

When I update the dictonary it need to be available in all processes. how can I achieve this

Comment: Use redis like everyone else?

Answer (score 2):

Mulitprocessing actually launches four separate instances of your application. Each with their own global interlock.  Which means they use separate memory for each instance.

This is by design.  You have 2 solutions.
Use a high speed dictionary store like Redis, or Memcached and connect all your servers to access that for their data needs.

OR

You can use gevent and GIPC to transfer data back and forth from separate running processes (must be on the same machine).  This has the added benefit of being async and still communicating data between the separate running processes.

https://github.com/jgehrcke/gipc

Comment: Celery is not a storage system.

Comment: I meant to put memcache.  Good catch.

Comment: How about the uwsgi caching framework? Will it work for this situation

Comment: Looks like it: "All of your caches can be accessed over the network. A request plugin named “cache” (modifier1 111) manages requests from external nodes. On a standard monolithic build of uWSGI the cache plugin is always enabled. The cache plugin works in a fully non-blocking way, and it is greenthreads/coroutine friendly so you can use technologies like gevent or Coro::AnyEvent with it safely."

Comment: Though redis is super simple, and I would advise going in that direction